# Salesforce Sandbox API Oauth2 Callback URL over localhost Django

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, salesforce, callbackurl

Newbie working on a Salesforce project for a job interview. I'm trying to build a Django form that will submit a case ticket to the Salesforce backend. Using [django-salesforce](https://github.com/django-salesforce/django-salesforce) [django-salesforce](https://github.com/django-salesforce/django-salesforce)library, and I'm at the point where I'm creating the a new connected app. How do I deal with the callback URL if I'm testing on localhost? The callback url needs to be an https secure connection. Can I just set the callback as http://localhost:8000? Having a hard time figuring it out and on a strict time limit so no time to learn the salesforce API.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. Because they will try to redirect you to that site also few oauth providers need it a valid url to do so.

You can use `https://ngrok.com` to publicly expose your local server.
`ngrok` exposes your local server and port to a publicly accessible url. Internally it created a tunnel from the generated url and your machine. So you can expose your local django server to world using it.

Then pass on the generated link to the OAuth app.